# Is there any difference in meaning between "cannot afford to + verb" and "cannot + verb"?

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference in meaning between the 2 patterns: "cannot afford to + verb" and "cannot + verb"?

For example:

1. *I cannot afford to wait forever* versus *I cannot wait forever*.
2. *I cannot afford to go* versus *I cannot go*.

Comment: Actually this is a real question.

Comment: If you could clarify the question, like giving some context, you might get an answer. As it is, yes there is a difference between them in some cases, but in other cases they can be equivalent. It depends on the situational context.

Comment: @JohnLawler: The available answers below have perfectly shed light on my confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Afford* is used here in the sense of *tolerate the burden of*. For example, we might say that we cannot *afford to buy this automobile*. This means the financial burden would be too much.

In your first example sentence, then, “I cannot afford to wait forever” means “I cannot tolerate the burden of waiting forever”. It means the cost (in time, money, or something else) of waiting forever is too much.

On the other hand, “I cannot wait forever” does not give a particular reason having to do with burden. It just says that waiting forever is not possible for you.

Answer (score 1):

The “effort” inclusion implies a cost to the person doing the action – if *I cannot afford to wait forever* I probably have a deadline, and the cost is missing it. If, on the other hand, *I cannot wait forever* it might be because I would get bored, or I would die before forever. The emphasis is on the cost element.

“Cost” may be financial, emotional, reputation. It focuses on this rather than the fact that I don’t want to do something.

Comment: I accept your answer too but I have no more green check mark left. :D